# Problems with my prepared statement update

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$query = "UPDATE kids_entry SET entries=? WHERE parentsemail=?";
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 'is',$entries,$parentsemail);
mysqli_execute($stmt1);
if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt1) != 1)
    die("issueasdass"); 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);
```

The above code does work for me on another page but i cannot seem to get it to work here. On the other page the set to update is a hardcoded in and is not dynamic so that might be why it isn't working for me. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is the type of $entries?  The 'is' you pass into the bind statement implies that your params will be an integer and a string.  If #entries is not a string, this could be causing some of your issues.

Comment: entries is an integer and parentsemail is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have resolved itself. Nothing has changed but now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that entries is the same value as what's already in the database? I don't think `*_affected_rows` returns 1 if nothing changes. Is it possible that there's more than 1 entry for 'parentsemail'? So perhaps `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows` is returning something like 2? Instead of checking 1, maybe let us know what `mysql_stmt_affected_rows` is returning. For example, from the docs:

> An integer greater than zero indicates
>   the number of rows affected or
>   retrieved. Zero indicates that no
>   records where updated for an
>   UPDATE/DELETE statement, no rows
>   matched the WHERE clause in the query
>   or that no query has yet been
>   executed. **-1 indicates that the query
>   has returned an error.**